# Laravel in Openshift: Class 'Swift_DependencyContainer' not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, openshift

I have got a Laravel 4.1 app running fine in local machine. After I deployed the app into OpenShift server, the following error comes out for every url.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Swift_DependencyContainer' not found in /var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/dependency_maps/cache_deps.php on line 3

Call Stack:
    0.0001     709376   1. {main}() /var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/public/index.php:0
    0.0002     710136   2. require('/var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/bootstrap/autoload.php') /var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/public/index.php:22
    0.0009     710624   3. require('/var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/autoload.php') /var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/bootstrap/autoload.php:17
    0.0011     713176   4. ComposerAutoloaderInit9a77102d4bf1b1e0412dc2447ab38eab::getLoader() /var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/autoload.php:7
    0.0028     830728   5. composerRequire9a77102d4bf1b1e0412dc2447ab38eab() /var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:52
    0.0028     831344   6. require('/var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_init.php') /var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:61
    0.0029     832008   7. require('/var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/dependency_maps/cache_deps.php') /var/lib/openshift/5232f4c55973ca6ee600020/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_init.php:22
```

But, I am not using any email functionality in my app. Searching on Google give me only one relevant result: https://github.com/loic-sharma/Messages/issues/29. But it is specific to Laravel 3, and doesn't contain a solution. So, do you have any idea what is causing above error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `composer update` or `composer install` command on your openshift gear ?
This article show you [how to deploy custom laravel 4 application to openshift](http://www.deploy2cloud.com/laravel/Deploy-Custom-laravel-4-Application-to-OpenShift)